# Mean curvature of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I'd like to know if there exist some meaning for the mean value of the curvature  function in a parametric function $r(t)$. This is a different topic of mean curvature in surfaces as in [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2051016/gaussian-curvature-mean-curvature).
For example, given the curve $r(t)=(\sin t + \sin 2t, \cos t + \cos 2t)$, the curvature is given by $\kappa=-\frac{6\cos t + 9}{4 \cos t + 5}$. Does it make any sense to compute the mean value of $\kappa$?

Comment: Up to my knowledge, there are results about maxima and minima of curvature for 2D curves but nothing about mean curvature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (signed) curvature $\kappa$ is the derivative of any function $\theta$ such that the unit tangent at $t$ is given by $(\cos(\theta(t)), \sin(\theta(t)))$. Thus, the mean curvature is
$$\frac{1}{b - a} \int_a^b \kappa(t) \, dt = \frac{\theta(b) - \theta(a)}{b - a},$$
which can be thought of as the average angular speed of the tangent line from $a$ to $b$.

Answer (score 0):

The mean can always be used to understand a varying number, so it might be useful in understanding the average curve. Also, I think that integrating the curvature over the curve over a section tells how many radians the curve has turned over that section, so integrating over the whole curve should give you $2\pi$ times the number of total loops and the average should be some notion of inverse average radius of the curve.

In general, I think the range of the curvature and a graph of the function are much more informative.